# Transformation of a plane

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

I have the $(x,y)$-plane $$\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | x,y\in \mathbb{R}, z = 0 \right\}.$$
I need a transformation matrix to transform this to the plane

$$ \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x+y+z=0 \right\}.$$

I found the Matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0  \\
-1 & -1 & 0  
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

This matrix does send the first plane bijectively to the second one, but it is not invertible. For example, you could take $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ as a third column.

Comment: yes, but is there any invertible matrix possible?

Comment: Of course yes, and the matrix I suggested is actually invertible. By the way, it is the same matrix @m.idaya suggested after.

Comment: You can also take $\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\sqrt{3}+3}{6} & \dfrac{\sqrt{3}-3}{6} & \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \\ \dfrac{\sqrt{3}-3}{6} & \dfrac{\sqrt{3}+ 3}{6} & \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \\ -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} & -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} & \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \end{pmatrix}$. This is the matrix of the rotation of axis directed by $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ which sends the normal of the first plane to the normal of the second plane.

Answer (score 0):

there are many choices of this type of transformation: for exempla
tack an as transform  a base of the   first plane in the base of the second  plane
and complete this transformation s.t transform a base of the first (beginnin) space
to a base of the second (arrival) space that is:
 $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ this is a
base for the first plane; $\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1)\}$ this is a base
for the second plane, so my transformation could transform the
first system in the second system above
 we complete this two system in a base respectively of $\Bbb{R}^3$
 (beginning and arrival spaces) so we choice (simply) respectively the
 vectors $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,1)$ and the transformation that
 choice  has matrix  in the canonical bases of $\Bbb{R}^3$ the matrix
 $P= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0&0  \\
0 & 1&0\\
-1&-1&1
\end{array}
\right)$